# AngularJS 1.4 directives: scope, two way binding and bindToController

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

> **Update**: It must have been something stupid in another part of the code. It works now, so the bindToController syntax is fine.

We are using AngularJS 1.4, which introduced a [new way to use bindToController](http://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/) in directives.

After quite a bit of reading (and maybe not understanding everything), we defined our directive like this:

```
  .directive('mdAddress', function mdAddress() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        address: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'modules/address/address.html',
      controller: AddressController,
      controllerAs: 'dir'
    };
```

Calling it from another view like this:

```
  <md-address address="vm.address"></md-address>
```

Having previously defined in the view controller:

```
  vm.address = {
    street: null,
    countryCode: null,
    cityCode: null,
    postalCode: null
  };
```

Referencing the variables in the directive template like this:

```
  <md-input-container>
    <label>{{'ADDRESSNUMBER' | translate}}</label>
    <input type="number" ng-model="dir.address.streetNumber">
  </md-input-container>
```

We spent 4h trying to figure out why our directive was not working. Well, it was working, but the two-way binding between the controller and the directive was not, `vm.address.street` was hopelessly set to null.

After a while, we just tried the old way:

```
  .directive('mdAddress', function mdAddress() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        address: '='
      },
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: 'modules/address/address.html',
      controller: AddressController,
      controllerAs: 'dir'
    };
```

And it magically worked. Any idea **WHY**?

Comment: What did you have in your `modules/address/address.html` template? If you were trying to reference `vm` at all in the template, then that would cause a null issue since `vm` doesn't exist in the scope of your directive.

Also if you were trying to just bind to `address` in the directive template, that also wouldn't exist as you're binding your controller as `dir`, so it would have to be `dir.address`

Comment: In the template we referenced the elements with `dir`:   `<input type="number" ng-model="dir.address.streetNumber">`. I edited the main post to clarify this. Thanks.

Comment: Please, provide two plunkers, for both cases. There is simple explanation for that, but it is plain text doesn't give a clear idea of what you exactly did.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue pre-upgrade to 1.4+. Any chance original issue was still referencing older version of Angular?

Comment: Hmm, it's a possibility, although I'm pretty sure we changed the angular version before trying this. Hard to tell right now :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:**

Thanks to the [reference to this blog post](http://toddmotto.com/no-scope-soup-bind-to-controller-angularjs/), I need to update my answer. Since AngularJS 1.4 it really seems, that you can use

```
scope: {},
bindToController: {
  variable: '='
}
```

which will do the (exact) same thing as the old syntax:

```
scope: {
  variable: '='
},
bindToController: true
```

The useful lines from the AngularJS source code to explain this behavior:

```
if (isObject(directive.scope)) {
  if (directive.bindToController === true) {
    bindings.bindToController = parseIsolateBindings(directive.scope,
                                                     directiveName, true);
    bindings.isolateScope = {};
  } else {
    bindings.isolateScope = parseIsolateBindings(directive.scope,
                                                 directiveName, false);
  }
}
if (isObject(directive.bindToController)) {
  bindings.bindToController =
      parseIsolateBindings(directive.bindToController, directiveName, true);
}
```

Source: [AngularJS 1.4.0](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0/angular.js)

**Original answer:**

Hopefully, I can explain you why this behavior you experienced is correct and where you did missunderstand the concept of scope binding there.

Let me explain, what you did in your first code snippet:

```
.directive('mdAddress', function mdAddress() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {},
      bindToController: {
        address: '='
      },
      templateUrl: 'modules/address/address.html',
      controller: AddressController,
      controllerAs: 'dir'
    };
```

With `scope: {}`, you created an isolated scope (without any inheritance) for your `mdAddress` directive. That means: No data is passed between the parent controller and your directive.

Having this in mind, regarding your second code snippet:

```
<md-address address="vm.address"></md-address>
```

`vm.address` from your parent controller/view will be assigned as expression to the address attribute of the directive, but as you defined an isolated scope before, the data is not passed into `AddressController` and therefore not available in the `bindToController` value.

Let's think of the `scope` object definition as the "which data will be passed in" and the `bindToController` as the "which data will be available in my view's controllerAs object".

So, now let's have a look at the last (and working code snippet):

```
.directive('mdAddress', function mdAddress() {
    var directive = {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        address: '='
      },
      bindToController: true,
      templateUrl: 'modules/address/address.html',
      controller: AddressController,
      controllerAs: 'dir'
    };
```

There you created an isolated scope, too, but this time you added the `address` attribute to be passed in as an expression. So now the `address` you passed in from the view in the second snippet will be available in the controller's scope. Setting `bindToController: true` now, will bind all the current scope's properties to the controller (or more likely the controllerAs object). And now, it works as you would expect, because data will be passed in to the scope and data will be passed out to the controller's template scope.

Did that brief overview help you to better understand the concept of the `scope` and `bindToController` definition objects?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It makes sense, and I fully understand the second part of your explanation, but the first part seem to say quite literally the opposite of the article I linked (about the new bindToController functionality). Specially when it says "This means we can move our scope: { name: '=' } example binding across to it to make it more explicit that isolate bindings are in fact inherited and bound to the controller", and replaces`scope: {name: '='}, bindToController: true` with `scope: {}, bindToController: {name: '='}`.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for your response. You're right, I need to revert parts of my answer. The important line is the one from the AngularJS source code mentioned in the article - so the behavior should be the same in both cases. So maybe you really had some strange bug/typo in your code? Or can you reproduce everything from your question? Very interesting topic!

Comment: Thanks, I thought I might have misunderstood the article :). Anyway, reviewing the AngularJS code, could it be that `scope: {}` returns `isObject` as true, since it's an empty object, not `null`? Then it would enter in the first part of the `if`sentence ... I checked the AngularJS source code for `isObject` but I'm not sure ...

Comment: Yes you are right, the first if condition will be evaluated to true in the case (as `{}` is indeed an object). Inside this if, the else branch will be triggered. But the second outer if condition will also be evaluated to true as `directive.bindToController` is also an object in your first code snippet. So `bindings.bindToController` and `bindings.isolateScope` will be populated. Don't know yet if this might run into these problems you had. It would really interesting to know if you can still reproduce the issue?!

Comment: Well, I must say I'm quite puzzled. It must have been something really stupid. We tried the exact same thing again today and it worked. Thank you for your help / time, and sorry for the inconvenience. I would swear it didn't work last week, but maybe it's something else we fixed in the meantime. No idea. Anyway, bindToController was not the problem. Thank you again!

Comment: "Did that brief overview help you to better understand the concept of the scope and bindToController definition objects?" Sure did for me!

Comment: @JimmyKane Thanks for your lovely feedback!

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer.