# using $scope over controllerAs in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having issues using controllerAs syntax in my directive and I'm not sure what the problem is (although I suspect something to do with isolated scope)

In a nutshell, I want to be able to access the properties of this directives controller in the view by using vm.options, vm.addOption etc.

```
function MultiChoiceQuestion() {
        var directive = {
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'widgets/multi-choice.html',
            controller: multiChoiceQuestionController,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            bindToController:true
        };
        return directive;
}

function multiChoiceQuestionController(){
            var vm = this;
            vm.options=[{name:"option1", answer:""}];

            vm.addOption = function(){                
                alert("add clicked");

            }

            vm.deleteOption = function(option){
                alert("delclicked");
            }
        }
```

In the HTML

```
<div ng-repeat="option in vm.options"> // this isn't working
```

I can use $scope to access these properties in the view and all works fine, but following John Papas styleguide, I'm trying to avoid using $scope.

```
function MultiChoiceQuestion() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'widgets/multi-choice.html',
        controller: multiChoiceQuestionController
    };
    return directive;
}

function multiChoiceQuestionController($scope){
        $scope.options=[{name:"option1", answer:""}];

        $scope.addOption = function(){}

        $scope.deleteOption = function(option){
           //
        }
    }
<div ng-repeat="option in options"> // works
```

I would greatly appreciate if someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: Set `bindToController: true` in the directive object.

Comment: Looking at your code though--is what you have here exactly what's in your JS file? You have a return statement before `multiChoiceQuestionController` is even reached.

Comment: You're right, tidied that up but still having the same problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861783/angularjs-1-4-directives-scope-two-way-binding-and-bindtocontroller

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Can you use the DOM inspector and inspect the `$scope` property on your `div`? You should be able to find `$scope.vm` when using the `controllerAs` syntax - just trying to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I created this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8ExhgbQhAs1KF0dV4gL?p=preview).

```
function MultiChoiceQuestion() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<div ng-repeat="option in vm.options">{{option.name}}</div>',
    controller: multiChoiceQuestionController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true
  };
  return directive;
}

function multiChoiceQuestionController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.options = [{
    name: "option1",
    answer: ""
  },
  {
    name: "option2",
    answer: ""
  }];

  vm.addOption = function() {
    alert("add clicked");

  }

  vm.deleteOption = function(option) {
    alert("delclicked");
  }
  vm.name = 'Pascals';
}
```

I replaced the templateURL with and inline template and it seems to work fine.Please check.

The only problem I see for your repeater not working is that options array has only 1 element.You might want to check with more than 1 element.