# Testing directive with bindToController and scope using karma

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

[[AngularJS 1.4 directives: scope, two way binding and bindToController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861783/angularjs-1-4-directives-scope-two-way-binding-and-bindtocontroller/33865538#338655])

Do any one tested the directive using karma, i am unable to get the scope.

```
beforeEach(inject(function(
        $rootScope,
        $compile) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        element = angular.element(
            "<div class='myAddress'>" +
            "<md-address address="vm.address"></md-address>" +
            "</div>"
            );
        $compile(element)(scope);

        scope = element.isolateScope() || element.scope();
    }));
```

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a scope.$apply() just after you call $compile, so:

```
beforeEach(inject(function(
    $rootScope,
    $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    element = angular.element(
      "<div class='myAddress'>" +
      "<md-address address="vm.address"></md-address>" +
    "</div>"
    );
    $compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$apply();
    scope = element.isolateScope();
  }));
```

Comment: No i used scope.$apply() as well scope.$digest(). i am unable to see the vm in scope object which is alias to controller

Comment: What do you actually want to test?

Comment: test template in directive which is bound with vm scope.

Comment: Ok but what will be your expectation in the test - 'It should...'?

Comment: it should define vms.address and lenght to be greater than zero, my intention is to get scope and i want to verify parent scope and child scope are both in one scope and i want to check

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me.... As it is inside div tag we need to find the directive and here interesting thing is we are not using isolated scope and it is inheriting parent scope to child scope.(element.isolateScope() doesn't work).

```
var directiveScope,scope,element;
beforeEach(inject(function(
    $rootScope,
    $compile) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();

    element = angular.element(
      "<div class='myAddress'>" +
      "<md-address address="vm.address"></md-address>" +
    "</div>"
    );
    $compile(element)(scope);
    directiveScope = element.isolateScope('my-address').scope();
  }));
```